# Custom Kernel faulting after loading bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, bootloader, osdev

I am having trouble with QEMU not loading my kernel from memory properly. I have been stuck on this problem for more than a day and i cannot find the root of the problem.

After a lot of debugging and researching i think the problem might be with the GDT. Although, when i tested the last working version of my kernel, it also incurred the same bug when i included more than one header file.

My code's REPO: https://github.com/lochyj/os

GDT.asm

```
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0          ; Base address of our segments


gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff       ; Segment length -> bits 0-15
    dw 0x0          ; Base address -> bits 0-15
    db 0x0          ; Base address -> bits 16-23
    db 10011010b    ; Flags -> 8 bits
    db 11001111b    ; Flags -> 4 bits + segment length -> bits 16-19
    db 0x0          ; Base address -> bits 24-31

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff       ; Segment length -> bits 0-15
    dw 0x0          ; Base address -> bits 0-15
    db 0x0          ; Base address -> bits 16-23
    db 10010010b    ; Flags -> 8 bits
    db 11001111b    ; Flags -> 4 bits + segment length -> bits 16-19
    db 0x0          ; Base address -> bits 24-31

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; Size of the gdt (16 bits)
    dd gdt_start    ; Address of the gdt (32 bits)

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Part of the CPU Dump from QEMU when running the img with -d int

```
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     1: v=0d e=0032 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000efdb pc=0000efdb SP=0010:0008fff4 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000010
EAX=00000010 EBX=00007d63 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000200
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00090000 ESP=0008fff4
EIP=0000efdb EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007ce6 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00000010 CCO=ADDB
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     2: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000efdb pc=0000efdb SP=0010:0008fff4 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000010
EAX=00000010 EBX=00007d63 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000200
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00090000 ESP=0008fff4
EIP=0000efdb EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00007ce6 00000017
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00000010 CCO=ADDB
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
```

The kernel should boot properly in theory, there are not compiler or linker errors and it seems there isnt any major discrepancies between the working img files and the broken img files when i compared them in vscode using the hex editor. the bootloader is the same in both working and non working versions and i see all of the data that is needed to run the kernel in both versions, so i dont understand why it doesnt boot.

I compiled and ran the kernel and bootloader in Arch for WSL on my windows 10 desktop.

I used QEMU, GCC, NASM and LD to compile the kernel and bootloader.

Any input is appreciated.

I am a beginner at OS dev and I'm still learning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `1: v=0d e=0032` decoded is v=0d #GP (general protection interrupt) and the error code [decoded](https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions#Selector_Error_Code) means you received exception 6 (invalid opcode) and it indexed into the IDT. You have no IDT (IDT=     00000000 000003ff suggests you haven't set one up and it is pointing at the real mode interrupt table) so it then double faulted. It appears the invalid opcode was executed at IP=0008:0000efdb . Have you checked to see what instruction is at that address?

Comment: No, i haven't looked at what is at that address. And i would have absolutely no idea how to see what is at that address.

Comment: You are using QEMU, you can set up GDB debugger to interface with a remote QEMU session. Learning how to debug a kernel is something you'll need to learn to do OS Development properly.

Comment: ok ill try that now

Answer (score 0):

For those who may come here later on. The problem was that i wasn't loading enough sectors from memory.